# C++ link error, symbol redefinition

Tags: visual-c++

I came across a problem recently.

I have three files, A.h, B.cpp, C.cpp:

A.h

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

int M()
{
    return 1;
}

#endif // __A_H__
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
```

C.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
```

As I comile the three files by MSVC, there is a error:

```
C.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl M(void)" (?M@@YAHXZ) already defined in B.obj
```

It is easy understanding, as we know, B.obj has a symbol named "M", also C.obj has a "M".
Here the error comes.

However, if I change M method to a class which contain a method M like this below:

A.h

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

class CA
{
public:
    int M()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

#endif // __A_H__
```

there is no more errors!! Could somebody tell me what is happening?

Comment: You cannot define function in header files, you declare them in header files. However, classes can be declared in header files. All the function definitions should go to source files except few inlines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If B.cpp and C.cpp include A.h, then both are compiled with your *definition* of `M`, so both object files will contain code for `M`. When the linker gathers all the functions, he sees that `M` is defined in two object files and does not know which one to use. Thus the linker raises an LNK2005.

If you put your function `M` into a class *declaration*, then the compiler marks/handles `M` as an inline function. This information is written into the object file. The linker sees that both object files contain a definition for an *inline* version of `CA::M`, so he assumes that both are equal and picks up randomly one of the two definitions.

If you had written

```
class CA {
public:
    int M();
};

int CA::M()
{
    return 1;
}
```

this would have caused the same problems (LNK2005) as your initial version, because then `CA::M` would not have been inline any more.

So as you might guess by now, there are two solutions for you. If you want `M` to be inlined, then change your code to

```
__inline int M()
{
    return 1;
}
```

If you don't care about inlining, then please do it the standard way and put the function *declaration* into the header file:

```
extern int M();
```

And put the function *definition* into a cpp file (for A.h this would ideally be A.cpp):

```
int M()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Please note that the `extern` is not really necessary in the header file.

Another user suggested that you write

```
static int M()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I'd not recommend this. This would mean that the compiler puts `M` into both of your object files and marks `M` as being a function that is only visible in each object file itself. If the linker sees that a function in B.cpp calls `M`, it finds `M` in B.obj and in C.obj. Both have `M` marked as static, so the linker ignores `M` in C.obj and picks the `M` from B.obj. Vice versa if a function in C.cpp calls `M`, the linker picks the `M` from C.obj. You will end up with multiple definitions of M, all with the same implementation. This is a waste of space.

Comment: This is a much more detailed answer and should be marked as the correct one, but from what I know static member should build only one copy of the function in memory, with no waste of space. I also feel to suggest to Quark to use a more C++Like approach to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's very detailed and helps.

Answer (score 0):

See http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node90.html how to do ifdef guards. You have to start with ifndef before the define.

Edit: Ah no, while your guard is wrong that's not the issue. Put static in front of your function to make it work. Classes are different because they define types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's under the hood, but if you don't need a class I guess that the compiler will automatically add the "extern" key to your functions, so you'll get the error including the header 2 times.

You can add the static keyword to M() method so you'll have only one copy of that function in memory and no errors at compile time.

By the way: I see you have a #endif, but not a #ifdef or #ifndef, is it a copy/paste error?